# Is it possible to find out if an id in a html-document is assigned twice?

Tags: html, dreamweaver

My id's are automatically assigned in the html-document and therefore unique, but if a user copy and pastes an item it is possible that an id exists twice.
Is it possible to check the document for a doubled id?
I work with Dreamweaver Version 11.0.

Comment: What do you mean by "a user copy and pastes an item"?

Comment: When the user drags and drops a Library Item it get's an id. But when a user copy and pastes this item instead of drag and drop it from the list it gets the same id, obviously because it's copied. That's my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dreamweaver is supposed to be able to provide validation (and having multiple IDs declared will throw a validation error) based on the declared doctype in the Window | Results | Validation tab but it's a little buggy and may not work properly.

You will have better luck and more consistent results by [running your page through the W3 Validator](http://validator.w3.org) service

Comment: Then there's no chance to automatize the process. Thank you for your answer.